# SQL update depending on values from view

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I thought this had to be a rather easy task, but I failed to see the complexity.

I have a table that I need refactoring, one of its FKs has duplicate entries only that they seem not to be as they have different case for names, say `FTP` and `ftp` for example

So, I've built a view that spits out a lowercase version of the duplicates with its id and the amount of times it has been used in the table I'm refactoring.  The reason I do this count is so that I can assign the id of the version of the record that has been used the most, in the hope that it will not have such a big impact on the UI when the record changes visually

So, the output of the view is something like this:

[image]

Ok, so here I want to keep 'tagger' with id = 1 and 'mytag' with id = 4 as they are the ones with higher usage (`countyCo`)

Now, I have table `tag`, which holds all the details for 'tagger' and 'mytag', and then I have the table `picture_tag` that is the one relating the tags to the pictures.

Output of `picture_tag` could be:

[image]

I added a 'name_aux' with the original names from the `tag` table to make them easier to link

I've tried several queries, but the issue I'm facing is how to group all the ids of the rows that have the "same" name in the `picture_tag` table and then assign the id with the `MAX countyCo` for the group of entries in the view that have the same value

So far everything I've done can't manage to use more than one entry and ends up assigning 'tagger' to every entry, overwriting 'mytag'

My last attempt looked like this:

```
UPDATE picture_tag SET tag_id = (SELECT id FROM duplicate_stuff WHERE (countyCo, name) IN (
SELECT MAX(countyCO), name FROM duplicate_stuff dst
JOIN picture_tag ptag
ON dst.id = ptag.tag_id
AND dst.name = LOWER(ptag.name_aux)
GROUP BY name))
```

But the subquery returned more than one element.

Another attempt was this one:

```
  UPDATE picture_tag ptag SET tag_id = (SELECT id FROM duplicate_stuff ds WHERE ds.name =
(SELECT LOWER(tag) FROM tag WHERE id = ds.id)
AND id = (SELECT id FROM tag WHERE id = ds.id)
ORDER BY ds.countyCo DESC
LIMIT 1
)
WHERE ptag.tag_id IN (SELECT id FROM duplicate_stuff)
```

But of course, the limit 1 has me overwriting the 'mytag' as well as the 'tagger'

Comment: Postgres or SQL Server? Those are two very different database products.

Comment: Ideally as agnostic as possible, so I can use the same liquibase script. However I've solved this issue as per answer bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hitting the right algorithm:

```
UPDATE picture_tag ptag
SET tag_id = (SELECT id FROM duplicate_stuff
WHERE name = LOWER(ptag.name_aux)
ORDER BY countyCo DESC
LIMIT 1)
WHERE LOWER(name_aux) IN (SELECT name FROM duplicate_stuff)
```

Or to avoid issues with MSSQL and its limit when using IN:

```
UPDATE picture_tag ptag
SET tag_id = (SELECT id FROM duplicate_stuff
WHERE name = LOWER(ptag.name_aux)
ORDER BY countyCo DESC
LIMIT 1)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT name FROM duplicate_stuff WHERE name = LOWER(name_aux))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER to get the tags that are used the most.  Then join this "duplicates" table with itself.  And join the table that you want to update.

Something like this:

```
WITH cte_tags
as
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY tagLower ORDER BY  Counter DESC ) as rn
FROM duplicate_stuff
)
UPDATE upd
SET TagId = tagMax.TagId
FROM cte_tags tagMax 
JOIN cte_tags tagNotMax on tagMax.tagLower = tagNotMax.tagLower and tagNotMax.rn>1
JOIN picture_tag upd on upd.tagId = tagNotMax.TagId
where tagmax.rn =1;
```

Comment: I don't quite follow, I already have a way to find the duplicates and count the amount of times they're used, what's more, my approach is cross-platform, while ROW_NUMBER isn't an option if using MySQL (I know I didn't mention this in the original question, but I always aim to having cross platform code) 

Same goes for PARTITION, and I'm unsure as to what tagLower and Counter would represent in my example.  Also, what is cte_tags?

Comment: However, I just tried this adapting tagLower to the name in the duplicate_stuff and Counter to the countyCo and taking cte_tags as an auxiliary table for the joins.  Didn't work, everything was updated to the id that has the higher countyCo (Counter) with no consideration for the name value